# How long it takes for a suspension of asking question and a permanent suspension from asking question?

Tags: discussion

I've asked 10 questions so far but half of them have downvotes because of bad quality questions.

How long it takes for a suspension of asking question and a permanent suspension from asking question? Am I on the brink of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the rules for the automated question bans are not well known, because they don't want to advertise them to encourage people to work around them.  They are designed to encourage you to improve the quality of your questions and answers.

However you can gain general advice on how to avoid automated bans from [this meta-stackexchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)